# Intervention Image resize different pictures under one

Tags: laravel

Laravel has `Intervention Image`, with which you can resize images

```
// create instance
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// resize image to fixed size
$img->resize(300, 200);
```

Everything is fine if the uploaded image has a size of 3000 x 2000 and we will make 300 x 200 from it.

But if we load images with different heights and widths, and do a 300 x 200 resize, then the images will stretch and look awful.

I need them to be cut a little at the edges.

I have tried using `$img->fit(300, 200);` but it cuts too much.

Is it possible to do two steps in `Intervention Image` for resizing, for example, defining the size and removing a few unnecessary parts to make the picture look more or less normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a few unnecessary parts you can use the crop() function first and then resize the image maintaining its aspect ration.

```
$img->crop(width, height, x, y);
```

This function cuts out a rectangular part of the current image with given width and height. Define optional x,y coordinates to move the top-left corner of the cutout to a certain position. By default the rectangular part will be centered on the current image if you do not provide the x,y co-ordinates.

After cropping the image, you can resize the image maintaining its aspect ration, so the image will not look stretchy or abnormal.

```
// resize the image to a width of 300 and constrain aspect ratio (auto height)
$img->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

// resize the image to a height of 200 and constrain aspect ratio (auto width)
$img->resize(null, 200, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
```

However, if you always want the image to be a specific dimension, which is in your case 300 X 200 , You can try the fit function with the callback functionality to retain maximal original image size.

```
// add callback functionality to retain maximal original image size
$img->fit(300, 200, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->upsize();
});
```

Comment: and what should I enter here? `$img->crop(width, height, x, y);` Let's say the first picture is 4220x2510, the second 1250x700. What values ​​should be in `width, height, x, y` for these two pictures to look normal?

Comment: By second picture do you mean the final outcome you want ?

Comment: no, the final result is 300x200, just if two pictures with this size are loaded, and so that both become 300x200

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check if it solves your issue.

Comment: this is one of the best solutions, but it cuts too much from the center, and the picture does not look very good

Comment: more precisely, the height cuts off strongly

Comment: For 4220x2510 dimension, the height is shorter for a 3:2 aspect ratio. in that case you can try to manually crop the image like $img->crop(height*1.5,height) where height is 2510 to get 3:2 ratio first and then resize the image by $img->resize(300,200)  to see if it outputs better result for you.